# Cleaning a harmonica with a blocked note

Tags: maintenance, harmonica

I have a harmonica which was given to be as a gift, I have no proper experience playing and maintaining a harmonica, nor do I still have the instructions. I could blow all 9 notes but the 10th. When I would blow it would create a very faint sound, which gives me the feeling that something may be blocking the airflow.

[image: Harmonica]
The harmonica above is the instrument in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it worked at one time, [this](http://www.harmonicaacademy.com/categories/20090103_1) page will probably have your solution. A blow note that doesn't work is generally solved by cleaning a little fuzz or hair out of the reed.

Comment: I ended up removing the outer plates. How do I 'inspect the reed which is not sounding'?

Comment: Visually, possibly with a magnifying glass. Look for lint, hair, or any kind of rust. If you do not see the problem, you might try passing the edge of a piece of paper into the gap between the reed and the plate to brush out anything invisible. If that has no effect, you might also compare the position of the reed to that of the other reeds, and take a look at the instructions given for adjusting the reed gap. Beware though; it's easy to ruin a reed by bending it.